# Polymer 1.0: how to access a property value inside a function

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I access the value of a property inside a function?
Here is the property

```html
properties:{
  name: {type: String}
}
```

```
<my-element name="Subrata"></my-element>
```

Inside `<my-element>` I have a function like this:

**Approach #1**

```html
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    ...
    ...
  </template>

  <script>
  (function () {
    is: 'my-element',
    properties:{
      name: {type: String}
    },
  
    getMyName: function(){
      return this.name;
    }
  })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

My another approach was to put the value inside an element but that did not work either.

**Approach #2**

```html
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <!-- value of name is rendered OK on the page -->
    <p id="maxp">{{name}}</p>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    (function() {
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        name: {type: String}
      },
      getMyName: function(){
          var maxpValue = this.$$("#maxp").innerHTML;
          return  maxpValue;
      }
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I accomplish this? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a self-invoking anonymous function, you should be using the `Polymer` function. Change `(function() { ... })();` in your code to read `Polymer({ ... });`.

Here's an example:

```html
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',

    properties: {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    },

    getMyName: function() {
      return this.name;
    }
  });
</script>
```

I suggest that you follow the [**Getting Started** guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html) from the Polymer documentation as it goes over all of this and more. It is a good starting point when you are looking to begin working with Polymer.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! But the workaround still shows this.name as undefined.

Comment: No problem! At what point are you setting the `name` property to a value? By default, when the element is instantiated, it will have a value of `undefined`. Are you looking to give it a default value?

Comment: No. I don't want to give it a default value. Rather the value needs to be passed via the property itself when the element itself is initialized from index.html like this: <my-element name="subrata"></my-element>. I want to grab this value only inside element's local DOM. In fact when I am using {{name}}, I can render the value. Just not getting the same inside the function getMyName().

Comment: Here's a live example of using the property: http://plnkr.co/edit/KeMjrb0mC4dn0jA3VGRG?p=preview - it seems to be working alright. Perhaps it may have to do with *when* you're trying to access the property. When do you read the property/call the function - when the document loads, on a certain event, etc.?

Comment: I am trying to read the call inside with a dom-repeat like this:
<template is="dom-repeat" filter="getMyName" observe="pname item.pname">

</template>

Comment: Would you mind throwing a bit of more code up onto the example in your question? I think it might help better understand what is happening if we could see a fuller example of the code that you're working with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80182/discussion-between-niladri-sarkar-and-vartan-simonian).

Comment: @VartanSimonian it looks like the new standard will be to put the `script` _inside_ the `dom-module`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735574/host-styles-have-no-effect/30736244?noredirect=1#comment49536077_30736244

Comment: @Zikes Hey, thanks for the heads up! Didn't see that one coming; they haven't documented anything yet about it, sounds like? (I don't blame them, it seems to have been a busy month for the team)

Comment: @VartanSimonian I did a little digging just to be sure: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/commit/3c70d64f1a9ca4b142c2202a3da6c423348e7a59

Comment: @Zikes Yup, sure looks shiny and official; I went ahead and edited my answer. You're the man!

Answer (score 2):

You could simple do

```
this.name
```

Anywhere in any function to access the variable